# Force SVG overlay to use same dimension of the underlying image

Tags: css, image, svg, overlay

I want to overlay my banner image with an svg that has some brand colours consisting of diagonal stripes on both the left and right side and is transparent in between.

In order to do so I use the pseudo element `after` to overlay the svg on the banner image. However, the svg takes up more width than the banner image on the right side and also more height.
Perhaps it's related to the svg's dimensions which are `width: 1280px` `height: 720px`. The image shows the png version of the SVG I want to use for overlaying the banner image.
[image: png version of SVG used for overlay]

How can I have the svg overlay cover the width of the banner img and scale down accordingly? I thought that because of the `position: absolute` the SVG would take up the dimension of the banner image. However, it doesn't.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how I can achieve the images to scale down responsively?

```css
.img-wrapper-overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden
}

.banner-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-img::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='1280' height='720' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' overflow='hidden'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3CclipPath id='clip0'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1280' height='720' /%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3CclipPath id='clip1'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='9.31323e-10' width='447675' height='447675' /%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3CclipPath id='clip3'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='447675' height='447675' /%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg clip-path='url(%23clip0)'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1280' height='720' fill='%23FFFFFF' fill-opacity='0' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0 634 0 0 182 634Z' fill='%23FFF578' fill-rule='evenodd' transform='matrix(1 -1.22465e-16 -1.22465e-16 -1 3.66662e-14 633)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0 723 0 0 207 723Z' fill='%23FFCB05' fill-rule='evenodd' transform='matrix(-1 0 0 1 1280 -3)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0 340 0 0 97 340Z' fill='%23FAA61A' fill-rule='evenodd' transform='matrix(-1 0 0 1 1280 380)' /%3E%3Cg clip-path='url(%23clip1)' transform='matrix(0.000104987 0 0 0.000104987 1159 663)'%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 banner-img">
      <div class="img-wrapper-overflow-hidden">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/345744/1440x520" alt="" title="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">
  

      <h1>Some Title</h1>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like on say a viewport with a very narrow aspect-ratio?

Comment: @AHaworth more or less similar to the image I've attached in my question. Yellow stripe on the left and two stripes on the right.

Comment: So how wide would the left hand yellow stripe be at the top?

Comment: @AHaworth the width isn't really defined. The only important factor is that it shouldn't be a line but more of a band.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to arise from the SVG being positioned absolutely but sized at 100% x 100% when the closest sized ancestor is not the immediate container.

This snippet positions the banner-img relative so its after pseudo element takes its size from it.

Then the background-image is given size 100% 100% so it will stretch as required.

```css
.img-wrapper-overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden
}

.banner-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner-img {
  position: relative;
  /* ADDED */
}

.banner-img::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* CHANGED */
  ;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='1280' height='720' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' overflow='hidden'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3CclipPath id='clip0'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1280' height='720' /%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3CclipPath id='clip1'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='9.31323e-10' width='447675' height='447675' /%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3CclipPath id='clip3'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='447675' height='447675' /%3E%3C/clipPath%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg clip-path='url(%23clip0)'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1280' height='720' fill='%23FFFFFF' fill-opacity='0' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0 634 0 0 182 634Z' fill='%23FFF578' fill-rule='evenodd' transform='matrix(1 -1.22465e-16 -1.22465e-16 -1 3.66662e-14 633)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0 723 0 0 207 723Z' fill='%23FFCB05' fill-rule='evenodd' transform='matrix(-1 0 0 1 1280 -3)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M0 340 0 0 97 340Z' fill='%23FAA61A' fill-rule='evenodd' transform='matrix(-1 0 0 1 1280 380)' /%3E%3Cg clip-path='url(%23clip1)' transform='matrix(0.000104987 0 0 0.000104987 1159 663)'%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 banner-img">
      <div class="img-wrapper-overflow-hidden">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/345744/1440x520" alt="" title="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1" role="main">


      <h1>Some Title</h1>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Hic nobis ipsum aut fugiat molestiae est impedit officia At perferendis quisquam est illo molestiae cum minus corrupti. Ab numquam corporis qui corporis temporibus in numquam deleniti. Ut maxime expedita quo facilis unde
        aut earum eaque non sunt porro ut ipsa blanditiis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```